# Why did adding the Debian testing repository create so many package dependencies?

Tags: debian, package-management, apt, geany

I have Debian 6.0.4, and I'm running an outdated Geany text editor package. There's no newer version available in the current stable repository, so I added testing packages to `sources.list`:

```
#debian testing
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ testing main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ testing main contrib non-free
```

And this is what I get for installation of the package:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  python-crypto mono-2.0-gac python-tagpy libcommons-collections3-java
  libhsqldb-java-gcj gstreamer0.10-alsa menu-xdg evolution-common
  geoclue-localnet libgnomekbd4 libtracker-client-0.8-0 gnome-utils-common
  libepc-ui-1.0-3 libpeas-common libpanel-applet-4-0 libboost-python1.46.1
  python-pyasn1 geoclue python-twisted-core evolution-webcal ekiga
  python-opengl libgtkmm-3.0-1 gir1.2-totem-1.0 rpm2cpio xsltproc gcalctool
  freedesktop-sound-theme libcolamd2.7.1 libnl-3-200 lp-solve telepathy-salut
  libarchive1 gnuchess-book gnome-nettool libxcb-render-util0 gnome-media
  gnome-games-extra-data libepc-1.0-3 gnome-desktop-data libgnomepanel2.24-cil
  aisle-themes liblouis-data
  a empathy-common sound-juicer
  qt4-qtconfig gnomine
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  abiword abiword-common accountsservice acl aisleriot alacarte apg apt aspell
  baobab brasero brasero-common cheese cheese-common colord console-setup
  console-setup-linux cpp-4.4 crda cups-pk-helper dbus dconf-gsettings-backend
  dconf-service dconf-tools debianutils dvd+rw-tools empathy empathy-common
  eog epiphany-browser epiphany-browser-data epiphany-extensions evince
  evince-common evolution evolution-common evolution-data-server
  evolution-data-server-common evolution-exchange evolution-plugins
  file-roller folks-common fonts-cantarell fonts-opensymbol gcalctool gcc-4.4
  gcc-4.4-base gcc-4.6-base gcj-4.4-base gcj-4.4-jre gcj-4.4-jre-headless
  gconf-defaults-service gconf-service gconf2 gconf2-common gdebi gdebi-core
  gdesklets gdm3 geany-common gedit gedit-common gedit-plugins gimp gimp-data
  gir1.2-accountsservice-1.0 gir1.2-atk-1.0 gir1.2-caribou-1.0
  gir1.2-clutter-1.0 gir1.2-clutter-gst-1.0 gir1.2-cogl-1.0
  gir1.2-coglpango-1.0 gir1.2-evince-3.0 gir1.2-folks-0.6 gir1.2-freedesktop
  gir1.2-gconf-2.0 gir1.2-gdata-0.0 gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 gir1.2-gee-1.0
  gir1.2-gkbd-3.0 gir1.2-glib-2.0 gir1.2-gmenu-3.0 gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0
  gir1.2-gnomekeyring-1.0 gir1.2-goa-1.0 gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-0.10
  gir1.2-gstreamer-0.10 gir1.2-gtk-3.0 gir1.2-gtkclutter-1.0
  gir1.2-gtksource-3.0 gir1.2-gucharmap-2.90 gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-3.0
  gir1.2-json-1.0 gir1.2-mutter-3.0 gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0
  gir1.2-panelapplet-4.0 gir1.2-pango-1.0 gir1.2-peas-1.0 gir1.2-polkit-1.0
  gir1.2-rb-3.0 gir1.2-soup-2.4 gir1.2-sushi-1.0 gir1.2-telepathyglib-0.12
  gir1.2-telepathylogger-0.2 gir1.2-totem-1.0 gir1.2-totem-plparser-1.0
  gir1.2-tracker-0.14 gir1.2-upowerglib-1.0 gir1.2-vte-2.90 gir1.2-webkit-3.0
  gjs glchess glib-networking glib-networking-common glib-networking-services
  glines gnect gnibbles gnobots2 gnome-applets gnome-applets-data
  gnome-backgrounds gnome-bluetooth gnome-contacts gnome-control-center
  gnome-control-center-data gnome-desktop3-data gnome-dictionary
  gnome-disk-utility gnome-documents gnome-font-viewer gnome-games
  gnome-games-data gnome-icon-theme gnome-icon-theme-extras
  gnome-icon-theme-symbolic gnome-keyring gnome-mag gnome-media gnome-menus
  gnome-nettool gnome-online-accounts gnome-packagekit gnome-packagekit-data
  gnome-panel gnome-panel-data gnome-power-manager gnome-screensaver
  gnome-screenshot gnome-search-tool gnome-session gnome-session-bin
  gnome-session-common gnome-settings-daemon gnome-shell gnome-shell-common
  gnome-sudoku gnome-sushi gnome-sushi-common gnome-system-log
  gnome-system-monitor gnome-system-tools gnome-terminal gnome-terminal-data
  gnome-themes-standard gnome-user-guide gnome-user-share gnome-utils-common
  gnome-video-effects gnomine gnotravex gnotski gnumeric gnumeric-common
  growisofs gsettings-desktop-schemas gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg gstreamer0.10-gconf
  gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad gstreamer0.10-plugins-base
  gstreamer0.10-plugins-good gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly
  gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio gtali gtk2-engines-pixbuf gucharmap gvfs
  gvfs-backends gvfs-bin gvfs-common gvfs-daemons gvfs-libs hamster-applet
  hpijs hplip hplip-cups hplip-data iagno imagemagick-common initscripts
  inkscape insserv iw krb5-locales krb5-multidev libaacs0 libabiword-2.9
  libaccountsservice0 libacl1 libapache2-mod-python libarchive12 libasound2
  libasound2-plugins libaspell15 libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data libatkmm-1.6-1
  libattr1 libavahi-ui-gtk3-0 libavcodec53 libavformat53 libavutil51
  libbluetooth3 libbluray1 libboost-python1.46.1 libbrasero-media3-1 libburn4
  libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6-dev libc6-i686 libcairo-gobject2 libcairo2
  libcamel-1.2-29 libcanberra-gtk3-0 libcanberra-gtk3-module libcanberra-pulse
  libcanberra0 libcap2-bin libcaribou-common libcaribou0 libchamplain-0.12-0
  libchamplain-gtk-0.12-0 libcheese-gtk20 libcheese1 libclutter-1.0-0
  libclutter-1.0-common libclutter-gst-1.0-0 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0
  libclutter-imcontext-0.1-0 libcluttergesture-0.0.2-0 libcogl-common
  libcogl-pango0 libcogl5 libcolord1 libcurl3-gnutls libcurl3-nss libdb5.1
  libdbus-glib1.0-cil libdbus1.0-cil libdconf0 libdirac-decoder0
  libdjvulibre-text libdjvulibre21 libdmapsharing-3.0-2 libdvbpsi7
  libebackend-1.2-1 libebml3 libebook-1.2-12 libecal-1.2-10
  libedata-book-1.2-11 libedata-cal-1.2-13 libedataserver-1.2-15
  libedataserverui-3.0-1 libepc-1.0-3 libepc-common libepc-ui-1.0-3
  libevent-2.0-5 libevince3-3 libevolution libexempi3 libfolks-eds25
  libfolks-telepathy25 libfolks25 libgail-3-0 libgail-common libgail18
  libgc1c2 libgcc1 libgcj10 libgcj10-awt libgck-1-0 libgconf-2-4 libgconf2-4
  libgcr-3-1 libgcr-3-common libgdata13 libgdict-1.0-6 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgdu-gtk0 libgdu0 libgeocode-glib0 libgfortran3
  libgimp2.0 libgirepository-1.0-1 libgjs0b libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin
  libglibmm-2.4-1c2a libgmime-2.6-0 libgmime2.6-cil libgmp10
  libgnome-bluetooth8 libgnome-control-center1 libgnome-desktop-3-2
  libgnome-keyring-common libgnome-keyring0 libgnome-media-profiles-3.0-0
  libgnome-menu-3-0 libgnome2-0 libgnome2-common libgnomekbd-common
  libgnomekbd7 libgnutls26 libgoa-1.0-0 libgoa-1.0-common libgoffice-0.8-8
  libgoffice-0.8-8-common libgomp1 libgpg-error0 libgphoto2-2 libgphoto2-l10n
  libgphoto2-port0 libgraphite2-2.0.0 libgrilo-0.1-0 libgssapi-krb5-2
  libgssrpc4 libgstreamer-plugins-bad0.10-0 libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0
  libgstreamer0.10-0 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common libgtk-vnc-2.0-0
  libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-bin libgtkhtml-4.0-0 libgtkhtml-4.0-common
  libgtkhtml-editor-4.0-0 libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a libgtkmm-3.0-1
  libgtksourceview-3.0-0 libgtksourceview-3.0-common libgucharmap-2-90-7
  libgvnc-1.0-0 libgweather-3-0 libhpmud0 libhunspell-1.3-0 libhyphen0
  libicu48 libimobiledevice2 libisofs6 libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0
  libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0 libjpeg8 libjs-jquery libjs-jquery-ui
  libjson-glib-1.0-0 libjson0 libjte1 libk5crypto3 libkadm5clnt-mit8
  libkadm5srv-mit8 libkate1 libkdb5-6 libkrb5-3 libkrb5-dev libkrb5support0
  liblcms2-2 libloudmouth1-0 libltdl7 liblzma5 libmagick++4 libmagickcore4
  libmagickwand4 libmatroska5 libmhash2 libmono-addins-gui0.2-cil
  libmono-addins0.2-cil libmono-cairo4.0-cil libmono-corlib2.0-cil
  libmono-corlib4.0-cil libmono-posix4.0-cil libmono-security4.0-cil
  libmono-sharpzip4.84-cil libmono-sqlite2.0-cil
  libmono-system-configuration4.0-cil libmono-system-core4.0-cil
  libmono-system-security4.0-cil libmono-system-web2.0-cil
  libmono-system-xml4.0-cil libmono-system2.0-cil libmono-system4.0-cil
  libmount1 libmozjs185-1.0 libmp3lame0 libmpfr4 libmtp-common libmtp-runtime
  libmtp9 libmutter0 libmx-1.0-2 libnautilus-extension1a libnettle4
  libnl-3-200 libnl-genl-3-200 libnl-route-3-200 libnm-glib4 libnm-gtk-common
  libnm-gtk0 libnm-util2 libnotify4 liboauth0 liboobs-1-5 liborc-0.4-0 libots0
  libp11-kit0 libpackagekit-glib2-14 libpam-gnome-keyring libpanel-applet-4-0
  libpango1.0-0 libpangomm-1.4-1 libpcre3 libpeas-1.0-0 libpeas-common
  libpixman-1-0 libpolkit-agent-1-0 libpolkit-backend-1-0
  libpolkit-gobject-1-0 libpoppler-glib6 libpoppler13 libportmidi0
  libpostproc52 libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulse0 libpython2.7 libqt4-dbus
  libqt4-designer libqt4-network libqt4-opengl libqt4-qt3support libqt4-script
  libqt4-sql libqt4-sql-mysql libqt4-sql-sqlite libqt4-svg libqt4-webkit
  libqt4-xml libqt4-xmlpatterns libqtcore4 libqtgui4 libqtwebkit4 libquadmath0
  libquvi-scripts libquvi7 libraptor2-0 librasqal3 librdf0
  libresid-builder0c2a librest-0.7-0 librest-extras-0.7-0 librhythmbox-core5
  librsvg2-2 librsvg2-common librtmp0 libsamplerate0 libsane-hpaio
  libschroedinger-1.0-0 libseed-gtk3-0 libsidplay2 libsmbclient
  libsocialweb-client2 libsocialweb0 libsoundtouch0 libsoup-gnome2.4-1
  libsoup2.4-1 libspandsp2 libssl1.0.0 libstartup-notification0 libstdc++6
  libsushi-1.0-0 libswscale2 libtag1-vanilla libtag1c2a libtalloc2 libtar0
  libtdb1 libtelepathy-glib0 libtelepathy-logger2 libtiff4 libtinfo5 libtirpc1
  libtotem-plparser17 libtotem0 libtracker-extract-0.14-0
  libtracker-miner-0.14-0 libtracker-sparql-0.12-0 libtracker-sparql-0.14-0
  libunique-3.0-0 libunistring0 libupower-glib1 libva-x11-1 libva1
  libvisual-0.4-0 libvisual-0.4-plugins libvlc5 libvlccore5 libvo-aacenc0
  libvo-amrwbenc0 libvpx1 libvte-2.90-9 libvte-2.90-common libvte-common
  libvte9 libwbclient0 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 libwebkitgtk-1.0-common
  libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 libwebkitgtk-3.0-common libwmf0.2-7 libwnck-3-0
  libwnck-3-common libwpd-0.9-9 libwpg-0.2-2 libwps-0.2-2 libwv-1.2-4
  libx264-120 libxalan2-java libxapian22 libxcb-composite0 libxcb-keysyms1
  libxcb-util0 libxcb-xfixes0 libxfixes3 libxklavier16 libxvidcore4 libyajl2
  libyelp0 libzvbi-common libzvbi0 linux-headers-2.6.32-5-common locales
  mahjongg make metacity-common mono-4.0-gac mono-gac mono-runtime
  multiarch-support mutter-common nautilus nautilus-data nautilus-dropbox
  nautilus-sendto nautilus-sendto-empathy network-manager
  network-manager-gnome nfs-common nfs-kernel-server notification-daemon nscd
  packagekit packagekit-backend-aptcc pkg-config planner planner-data
  policykit-1 poppler-data printer-driver-hpcups printer-driver-hpijs
  pulseaudio pulseaudio-esound-compat pulseaudio-module-x11 pulseaudio-utils
  python python-apt python-brlapi python-cairo python-compizconfig
  python-crypto python-cups python-dbus python-evolution python-gconf
  python-gdbm python-gi python-gi-cairo python-glade2 python-gmenu
  python-gnome2 python-gnomedesktop python-gnomekeyring python-gobject
  python-gobject-2 python-gpgme python-gst0.10 python-gtk2 python-gtkglext1
  python-gtksourceview2 python-httplib2 python-imaging python-libxml2
  python-lxml python-markupsafe python-minimal python-mysqldb python-notify
  python-numpy python-openssl python-packagekit python-pkg-resources
  python-pycurl python-pygame python-pyorbit python-pysqlite2 python-rdflib
  python-reportlab python-software-properties python-support python-tagpy
  python-twisted-bin python-twisted-conch python-twisted-core
  python-twisted-web python-vte python-webkit python-wnck python-xapian
  python-zope.interface python2.7 python2.7-minimal qdbus qt4-qtconfig
  quadrapassel rhythmbox rhythmbox-data rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder
  rhythmbox-plugins rpcbind rsyslog rtkit samba samba-common seahorse
  smbclient sound-juicer swat telepathy-logger tomboy totem totem-common
  totem-mozilla totem-plugins tracker uno-libs3 update-manager-core
  update-manager-gnome update-notifier update-notifier-common ure vinagre vino
  vlc vlc-data vlc-nox vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-pulse winbind
  wireless-regdb wpasupplicant yelp yelp-xsl zeitgeist-core zenity
  zenity-common zlib1g zlib1g-dev
Suggested packages:
  dpkg-dev apt-doc lzma aspell-doc spellutils vcdimager libdvdcss2
  gcc-4.4-locales cdrskin telepathy-haze telepathy-butterfly unrar
  evolution-dbg evolution-plugins-experimental evolution-data-server-dbg
  evolution-exchange-dbg arj lha lzip lzop ncompress rzip sharutils unace
  unalz zoo gcc-4.4-multilib libmudflap0-4.4-dev gcc-4.4-doc libgcc1-dbg
  libgomp1-dbg libmudflap0-dbg libcloog-ppl0 libppl-c2 libppl7 fastjar
  gcj-4.4-jdk xz-lzma doc-base gimp-help-en gimp-help gimp-data-extras
  gnome-hearts gnome-video-effects-frei0r gnumeric-doc gnumeric-plugins-extra
  frei0r-plugins hplip-gui hplip-doc dia dia-gnome libsvg-perl libxml-xql-perl
  python-uniconvertor skencil bootchart krb5-doc libapache2-mod-python-doc
  libbluray-bdj python3 glibc-doc libcap-dev libgcj10-dbg gphoto2 gtkam
  krb5-user libjs-jquery-ui-docs liblcms2-utils libmagickcore4-extra
  libmono-i18n2.0-cil libmono-i18n4.0-all libmono-winforms2.0-cil libgamin0
  ttf-baekmuk ttf-arphic-gbsn00lp ttf-arphic-bsmi00lp ttf-arphic-gkai00mp
  ttf-arphic-bkai00mp libqt4-dev raptor2-utils rasqal-utils
  librdf-storage-postgresql librdf-storage-mysql librdf-storage-sqlite
  redland-utils librsvg2-bin libxalan2-java-doc libbsf-java libxsltc-java
  xapian-tools make-doc avahi-autoipd network-manager-openvpn-gnome
  network-manager-vpnc-gnome network-manager-pptp-gnome
  packagekit-backend-smart hpijs-ppds pavumeter pavucontrol paman paprefs
  python-tk python-apt-dbg python-apt-doc python-crypto-dbg python-crypto-doc
  python-dbus-doc python-dbus-dbg python-gnome2-doc python-gdbm-dbg
  python-gtk2-doc python-gobject-2-dbg python-gst0.10-dev python-gst0.10-dbg
  libgtksourceview2.0-dev python-imaging-doc python-imaging-dbg
  python-lxml-dbg python-egenix-mxdatetime python-mysqldb-dbg python-numpy-doc
  python-numpy-dbg python-nose python-dev gfortran python-openssl-doc
  python-openssl-dbg python-distribute python-distribute-doc
  libcurl4-gnutls-dev python-pycurl-dbg timidity python-pysqlite2-doc
  python-pysqlite2-dbg python-egenix-mxtexttools python-reportlab-doc
  python-twisted-bin-dbg python-qt3 python-wxgtk2.8 xapian-doc python2.7-doc
  rsyslog-mysql rsyslog-pgsql rsyslog-doc rsyslog-gnutls rsyslog-gssapi
  rsyslog-relp smbldap-tools ldb-tools ctdb gstreamer0.10-lame
  gstreamer0.10-plugins-really-bad tasque gromit ubuntu-system-service
  cli-uno-bridge videolan-doc wpagui libengine-pkcs11-openssl
  zeitgeist-datahub
Recommended packages:
  abiword-plugin-grammar abiword-plugin-mathview fonts-liberation unoconv
  gnome-session-fallback grilo-plugins-0.1 libmono-i18n-west4.0-cil
  planner-doc python-reportlab-accel python-renderpm tdb-tools tracker-utils
  tracker-gui tracker-miner-fs tracker-miner-evolution apport-gtk rdesktop
  libpam-winbind
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  capplets-data console-terminus deskbar-applet gcc-4.3 gir1.0-clutter-1.0
  gir1.0-freedesktop gir1.0-glib-2.0 gir1.0-gstreamer-0.10 gir1.0-gtk-2.0
  gir1.0-json-glib-1.0 gnome gnome-accessibility gnome-core
  gnome-desktop-environment libbrasero-media0 libepc-1.0-2 libepc-ui-1.0-2
  libmetacity-private0 libmtp8 libnautilus-extension1 libpolkit-gtk-1-0
  libseed0 libtar libvlccore4 linux-headers-2.6-686 linux-headers-2.6.32-5-686
  metacity openoffice.org openoffice.org-base openoffice.org-base-core
  openoffice.org-calc openoffice.org-common openoffice.org-core
  openoffice.org-draw openoffice.org-emailmerge openoffice.org-evolution
  openoffice.org-filter-binfilter openoffice.org-filter-mobiledev
  openoffice.org-gcj openoffice.org-gnome openoffice.org-gtk
  openoffice.org-help-en-gb openoffice.org-help-en-us openoffice.org-impress
  openoffice.org-java-common openoffice.org-math openoffice.org-officebean
  openoffice.org-report-builder-bin openoffice.org-style-galaxy
  openoffice.org-style-tango openoffice.org-thesaurus-en-us
  openoffice.org-writer portmap python-gnomeapplet python-psyco python-uno
  seahorse-plugins totem-coherence
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  abiword abiword-common accountsservice acl aisleriot apg colord
  console-setup-linux crda dconf-gsettings-backend dconf-service dconf-tools
  folks-common fonts-cantarell fonts-opensymbol gcc-4.6-base gconf-service
  geany-common gir1.2-accountsservice-1.0 gir1.2-atk-1.0 gir1.2-caribou-1.0
  gir1.2-clutter-1.0 gir1.2-clutter-gst-1.0 gir1.2-cogl-1.0
  gir1.2-coglpango-1.0 gir1.2-evince-3.0 gir1.2-folks-0.6 gir1.2-freedesktop
  gir1.2-gconf-2.0 gir1.2-gdata-0.0 gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 gir1.2-gee-1.0
  gir1.2-gkbd-3.0 gir1.2-glib-2.0 gir1.2-gmenu-3.0 gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0
  gir1.2-gnomekeyring-1.0 gir1.2-goa-1.0 gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-0.10
  gir1.2-gstreamer-0.10 gir1.2-gtk-3.0 gir1.2-gtkclutter-1.0
  gir1.2-gtksource-3.0 gir1.2-gucharmap-2.90 gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-3.0
  gir1.2-json-1.0 gir1.2-mutter-3.0 gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0
  gir1.2-panelapplet-4.0 gir1.2-pango-1.0 gir1.2-peas-1.0 gir1.2-polkit-1.0
  gir1.2-rb-3.0 gir1.2-soup-2.4 gir1.2-sushi-1.0 gir1.2-telepathyglib-0.12
  gir1.2-telepathylogger-0.2 gir1.2-totem-1.0 gir1.2-totem-plparser-1.0
  gir1.2-tracker-0.14 gir1.2-upowerglib-1.0 gir1.2-vte-2.90 gir1.2-webkit-3.0
  gjs glchess glib-networking glib-networking-common glib-networking-services
  glines gnect gnibbles gnobots2 gnome-contacts gnome-control-center-data
  gnome-desktop3-data gnome-documents gnome-font-viewer
  gnome-icon-theme-extras gnome-icon-theme-symbolic gnome-online-accounts
  gnome-packagekit gnome-packagekit-data gnome-shell gnome-shell-common
  gnome-sudoku gnome-sushi gnome-sushi-common gnome-themes-standard
  gnome-video-effects gnomine gnotravex gnotski gnumeric gnumeric-common
  growisofs gsettings-desktop-schemas gstreamer0.10-gconf
  gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio gtali gvfs-common gvfs-daemons gvfs-libs iagno
  imagemagick-common iw krb5-locales libaacs0 libabiword-2.9
  libaccountsservice0 libarchive12 libasound2-plugins libatkmm-1.6-1
  libavahi-ui-gtk3-0 libavcodec53 libavformat53 libavutil51 libbluray1
  libboost-python1.46.1 libbrasero-media3-1 libcairo-gobject2 libcamel-1.2-29
  libcanberra-gtk3-0 libcanberra-gtk3-module libcanberra-pulse libcap2-bin
  libcaribou-common libcaribou0 libchamplain-0.12-0 libchamplain-gtk-0.12-0
  libcheese-gtk20 libcheese1 libclutter-1.0-common libclutter-gst-1.0-0
  libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libclutter-imcontext-0.1-0 libcluttergesture-0.0.2-0
  libcogl-common libcogl-pango0 libcogl5 libcolord1 libcurl3-nss libdb5.1
  libdbus-glib1.0-cil libdbus1.0-cil libdconf0 libdirac-decoder0
  libdmapsharing-3.0-2 libdvbpsi7 libebackend-1.2-1 libebml3 libebook-1.2-12
  libecal-1.2-10 libedata-book-1.2-11 libedata-cal-1.2-13
  libedataserver-1.2-15 libedataserverui-3.0-1 libepc-1.0-3 libepc-ui-1.0-3
  libevent-2.0-5 libevince3-3 libfolks-eds25 libfolks-telepathy25 libfolks25
  libgail-3-0 libgck-1-0 libgconf-2-4 libgcr-3-1 libgcr-3-common libgdata13
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgeocode-glib0
  libgirepository-1.0-1 libgjs0b libglib2.0-bin libgmime-2.6-0 libgmime2.6-cil
  libgmp10 libgnome-bluetooth8 libgnome-control-center1 libgnome-desktop-3-2
  libgnome-keyring-common libgnome-media-profiles-3.0-0 libgnome-menu-3-0
  libgnomekbd7 libgoa-1.0-0 libgoa-1.0-common libgoffice-0.8-8
  libgoffice-0.8-8-common libgphoto2-l10n libgraphite2-2.0.0 libgrilo-0.1-0
  libgstreamer-plugins-bad0.10-0 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common
  libgtk-vnc-2.0-0 libgtkhtml-4.0-0 libgtkhtml-4.0-common
  libgtkhtml-editor-4.0-0 libgtkmm-3.0-1 libgtksourceview-3.0-0
  libgtksourceview-3.0-common libgucharmap-2-90-7 libgvnc-1.0-0
  libgweather-3-0 libhunspell-1.3-0 libicu48 libimobiledevice2
  libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0 libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0 libjpeg8 libjs-jquery
  libjs-jquery-ui libjson0 libjte1 libkadm5clnt-mit8 libkadm5srv-mit8
  libkdb5-6 liblcms2-2 libloudmouth1-0 liblzma5 libmagick++4 libmagickcore4
  libmagickwand4 libmatroska5 libmhash2 libmono-cairo4.0-cil
  libmono-corlib4.0-cil libmono-posix4.0-cil libmono-security4.0-cil
  libmono-sharpzip4.84-cil libmono-system-configuration4.0-cil
  libmono-system-core4.0-cil libmono-system-security4.0-cil
  libmono-system-xml4.0-cil libmono-system4.0-cil libmount1 libmozjs185-1.0
  libmp3lame0 libmtp-common libmtp-runtime libmtp9 libmutter0 libmx-1.0-2
  libnautilus-extension1a libnettle4 libnl-3-200 libnl-genl-3-200
  libnl-route-3-200 libnm-glib4 libnm-gtk-common libnm-gtk0 libnm-util2
  libnotify4 liboauth0 liboobs-1-5 libots0 libp11-kit0 libpackagekit-glib2-14
  libpanel-applet-4-0 libpeas-1.0-0 libpeas-common libpoppler-glib6
  libpoppler13 libportmidi0 libpostproc52 libpython2.7 libqtwebkit4
  libquadmath0 libquvi-scripts libquvi7 libraptor2-0 librasqal3
  libresid-builder0c2a librest-0.7-0 librest-extras-0.7-0 librhythmbox-core5
  librtmp0 libsamplerate0 libseed-gtk3-0 libsidplay2 libsocialweb-client2
  libsocialweb0 libsoundtouch0 libspandsp2 libssl1.0.0 libsushi-1.0-0
  libswscale2 libtar0 libtelepathy-logger2 libtinfo5 libtirpc1 libtotem0
  libtracker-extract-0.14-0 libtracker-miner-0.14-0 libtracker-sparql-0.12-0
  libtracker-sparql-0.14-0 libunique-3.0-0 libunistring0 libva-x11-1 libva1
  libvlccore5 libvo-aacenc0 libvo-amrwbenc0 libvpx1 libvte-2.90-9
  libvte-2.90-common libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 libwebkitgtk-1.0-common
  libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 libwebkitgtk-3.0-common libwnck-3-0 libwnck-3-common
  libwpd-0.9-9 libwpg-0.2-2 libwps-0.2-2 libwv-1.2-4 libx264-120
  libxalan2-java libxcb-composite0 libxcb-util0 libxcb-xfixes0 libxvidcore4
  libyajl2 libyelp0 libzvbi-common libzvbi0 mahjongg mono-4.0-gac
  multiarch-support mutter-common packagekit packagekit-backend-aptcc
  planner-data poppler-data printer-driver-hpcups printer-driver-hpijs
  pulseaudio pulseaudio-esound-compat pulseaudio-module-x11 pulseaudio-utils
  python-gi python-gi-cairo python-gobject-2 python-gpgme python-packagekit
  python-pycurl python-reportlab python2.7 python2.7-minimal qdbus
  quadrapassel rhythmbox-data rpcbind rtkit telepathy-logger tracker vinagre
  wireless-regdb yelp-xsl zeitgeist-core zenity-common
The following packages will be upgraded:
  alacarte apt aspell baobab brasero brasero-common cheese cheese-common
  console-setup cpp-4.4 cups-pk-helper dbus debianutils dvd+rw-tools empathy
  empathy-common eog epiphany-browser epiphany-browser-data
  epiphany-extensions evince evince-common evolution evolution-common
  evolution-data-server evolution-data-server-common evolution-exchange
  evolution-plugins file-roller gcalctool gcc-4.4 gcc-4.4-base gcj-4.4-base
  gcj-4.4-jre gcj-4.4-jre-headless gconf-defaults-service gconf2 gconf2-common
  gdebi gdebi-core gdesklets gdm3 geany gedit gedit-common gedit-plugins gimp
  gimp-data gnome-applets gnome-applets-data gnome-backgrounds gnome-bluetooth
  gnome-control-center gnome-dictionary gnome-disk-utility gnome-games
  gnome-games-data gnome-icon-theme gnome-keyring gnome-mag gnome-media
  gnome-menus gnome-nettool gnome-panel gnome-panel-data gnome-power-manager
  gnome-screensaver gnome-screenshot gnome-search-tool gnome-session
  gnome-session-bin gnome-session-common gnome-settings-daemon
  gnome-system-log gnome-system-monitor gnome-system-tools gnome-terminal
  gnome-terminal-data gnome-user-guide gnome-user-share gnome-utils-common
  gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad gstreamer0.10-plugins-base
  gstreamer0.10-plugins-good gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly gtk2-engines-pixbuf
  gucharmap gvfs gvfs-backends gvfs-bin hamster-applet hpijs hplip hplip-cups
  hplip-data initscripts inkscape insserv krb5-multidev libacl1
  libapache2-mod-python libasound2 libaspell15 libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data
  libattr1 libbluetooth3 libburn4 libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6-dev
  libc6-i686 libcairo2 libcanberra0 libclutter-1.0-0 libcurl3-gnutls
  libdjvulibre-text libdjvulibre21 libepc-common libevolution libexempi3
  libgail-common libgail18 libgc1c2 libgcc1 libgcj10 libgcj10-awt libgconf2-4
  libgdict-1.0-6 libgdu-gtk0 libgdu0 libgfortran3 libgimp2.0 libglib2.0-0
  libglibmm-2.4-1c2a libgnome-keyring0 libgnome2-0 libgnome2-common
  libgnomekbd-common libgnutls26 libgomp1 libgpg-error0 libgphoto2-2
  libgphoto2-port0 libgssapi-krb5-2 libgssrpc4 libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0
  libgstreamer0.10-0 libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-bin libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a libhpmud0
  libhyphen0 libisofs6 libjson-glib-1.0-0 libk5crypto3 libkate1 libkrb5-3
  libkrb5-dev libkrb5support0 libltdl7 libmono-addins-gui0.2-cil
  libmono-addins0.2-cil libmono-corlib2.0-cil libmono-sqlite2.0-cil
  libmono-system-web2.0-cil libmono-system2.0-cil libmpfr4 liborc-0.4-0
  libpam-gnome-keyring libpango1.0-0 libpangomm-1.4-1 libpcre3 libpixman-1-0
  libpolkit-agent-1-0 libpolkit-backend-1-0 libpolkit-gobject-1-0
  libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulse0 libqt4-dbus libqt4-designer libqt4-network
  libqt4-opengl libqt4-qt3support libqt4-script libqt4-sql libqt4-sql-mysql
  libqt4-sql-sqlite libqt4-svg libqt4-webkit libqt4-xml libqt4-xmlpatterns
  libqtcore4 libqtgui4 librdf0 librsvg2-2 librsvg2-common libsane-hpaio
  libschroedinger-1.0-0 libsmbclient libsoup-gnome2.4-1 libsoup2.4-1
  libstartup-notification0 libstdc++6 libtag1-vanilla libtag1c2a libtalloc2
  libtdb1 libtelepathy-glib0 libtiff4 libtotem-plparser17 libupower-glib1
  libvisual-0.4-0 libvisual-0.4-plugins libvlc5 libvte-common libvte9
  libwbclient0 libwmf0.2-7 libxapian22 libxcb-keysyms1 libxfixes3
  libxklavier16 linux-headers-2.6.32-5-common locales make metacity-common
  mono-gac mono-runtime nautilus nautilus-data nautilus-dropbox
  nautilus-sendto nautilus-sendto-empathy network-manager
  network-manager-gnome nfs-common nfs-kernel-server notification-daemon nscd
  pkg-config planner policykit-1 python python-apt python-brlapi python-cairo
  python-compizconfig python-crypto python-cups python-dbus python-evolution
  python-gconf python-gdbm python-glade2 python-gmenu python-gnome2
  python-gnomedesktop python-gnomekeyring python-gobject python-gst0.10
  python-gtk2 python-gtkglext1 python-gtksourceview2 python-httplib2
  python-imaging python-libxml2 python-lxml python-markupsafe python-minimal
  python-mysqldb python-notify python-numpy python-openssl
  python-pkg-resources python-pygame python-pyorbit python-pysqlite2
  python-rdflib python-software-properties python-support python-tagpy
  python-twisted-bin python-twisted-conch python-twisted-core
  python-twisted-web python-vte python-webkit python-wnck python-xapian
  python-zope.interface qt4-qtconfig rhythmbox rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder
  rhythmbox-plugins rsyslog samba samba-common seahorse smbclient sound-juicer
  swat tomboy totem totem-common totem-mozilla totem-plugins uno-libs3
  update-manager-core update-manager-gnome update-notifier
  update-notifier-common ure vino vlc vlc-data vlc-nox vlc-plugin-notify
  vlc-plugin-pulse winbind wpasupplicant yelp zenity zlib1g zlib1g-dev
327 upgraded, 363 newly installed, 58 to remove and 1116 not upgraded.
Need to get 627 MB of archives.
After this operation, 84.4 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? n
```

I'm not sure it's good idea to install all of this. Why is it doing so much to my system just to update one text editor?

Comment: Is the [version in backports](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze-backports/geany) still too old for your purposes?

Comment: Configure your `/etc/apt/preferences` file if you want to keep those sources and don't want to upgrade to testing. See `man apt_preferences`.

Answer (score 8):

It brought in those many dependencies because you're upgrading to Testing.

This can be seen from the many GTK 3.0-related packages which are brought by GNOME 3, and due to the fact that kernel 2.6 (`linux-headers-2.6.32-5-686`) is being removed (because testing uses a more recent kernel).

If you want a more recent Geany on your stable Debian, I'd look for [backports](http://backports-master.debian.org/Packages/)
 and, if none are available, build your own.

Comment: thanks, I found in backports version 0.2, it's not the latest but it will do,

Comment: and what do you mean by building my own, to compile it from source code?

Comment: @user1089548 yes.

Comment: @user1089548: You could make your own backport. It is not that hard.